# yaml-cpp: create an undefined node

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

in yaml-cpp, how can I create a node that evaluates to false in a boolean context (which seems to be equivalent to `!node.IsDefined()`)?

currently I'm using

```
Node null = Node()["x"];
assert(!null);
```

which works for any string - but that seems to be arbitrary and not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, and the reason is that the only thing that returns an undefined node is `operator[]` on a `const Node`, when the key doesn't exist. It perhaps is more clearly written as follows, but this is essentially the same as what you've written.

```
const Node node;
assert(!node["x"]);
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you please explain why this piece of code is an answer to the question?

Comment: The OP asked how to create a Node that evaluates to false in a boolean context. The answer is a short snippet of code. The first line of the answer is an explanation of why their example didn't work.

Comment: How is this substantively different to the code in the question?

Comment: The `const` keyword. Hence the first line of my answer :)

Comment: But the rvalue `Node()` in the question selects the same `operator[] const`, so it's exactly the some code.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread the question. I didn't realize that the OP *had* a working solution, and didn't notice that the `operator[]` chosen would be `const`. I rephrased my answer to confirm the OP's solution and explain why that was it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as

```
YAML::Node(YAML::NodeType::Undefined)
```